# How to instance Class from Header selecting a proper CTOR?

Tags: c++, class, init

Let say I've this class:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    bool mIsMeter = false;

public:
    MyClass(bool isMeter = false) {
        mIsMeter = isMeter;
    }
    ~MyClass() {

    }
};
```

Now, within `myClasses.h`, I write:

```
MyClass mMyClass;
```

it instance the class using the default CTOR in the stack (in my example, using `isMeter = false`). What if I want (from there) init the class passing `true` as parameter?

I could do it in `myClasses.cpp`, but than it will create first the stack oversion of `mMyClass` with `false`, then re-allocate it using `mMyClass = MyClass(true)`.

Isn't a waste of resource? Can't just init it from header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every variable definition can include an initialiser. In your case, you'd do it like this:

```
MyClass mMyClass(true);
```

Note that this assumes that `mMyClass` is a global (or namespace-scope) variable. If that is the case, just be aware that it will be defined in *each* file which includes the header. So if you include it in more than one file, you'll get linker errors (multiple definition).

If `mMyClass` is actually a member declared within another class definition (which the name starting with `m` seems to indicate), the multiple-definition comment of course doesn't apply. It's still possible to initialise `mMyClass` at declaration, but you'll have to use either copy-initialisation or list-initialisation:

```
// either
MyClass mMyClass = true; // this one might call copy ctor
// or
MyClass mMyClass{true}; // this one guarantees one ctor call only
```

However, you can also initialise it as part of the mem-initializer-list of the constructor of the containing class. That would be something like this:

```
class OtherClass
{
  MyClass mMyClass;

public:
  OtherClass(int i) : mMyClass(i > 42) {}
};
```

Comment: I can't write MyClass mMyClass(true); in the header file. It says `Error, expected type identifier`

Comment: @paizza Then you're putting it in the wrong place. Since you haven't shown a [mcve] in your question, it's hard for me to say more.

Comment: Here you go: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e31a2ef96ae46430 I can't do `MyClass mMyClass(true);`, only `MyClass mMyClass;`

Comment: @paizza Oops, you're right. I forgot that in-class initialisation requires copy or list style; answer amended.

Comment: Oh, you pass parameters as list. Not sure about the differences? What do you mean with "this one might call copy ctor"?

Comment: @paizza It means that it might first create a temporary `MyClass(true)` and then copy (or move) that into `mMyClass`. Of course, in practice, it will most likely elide that copy/move altogether.

Comment: And if you have two param? what about first way?

Comment: @paizza Just like you'd do it in any other definition: `MyClass mMyClass = {a, b, c};` or `MyClass mMyClass = MyClass{a, b, c};`.